# Confused about “iptables” chains and why some traffic is blocked but not other traffic

Tags: networking, iptables

When I add these rules to INPUT:

```
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -m recent --name ping --set
-A INPUT -m recent --name ping --hitcount 3 --rcheck --seconds 20 -j DROP
```

this will ban (all connection types) from the IP address(es) from the `ping` list – those who try to ping 3 times in 20 seconds.

However, when I redirect the traffic to another chain:

```
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j BAN
```

and do the same in this same chain:

```
-A BAN -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -m recent --name ping --set
-A BAN -m recent --name ping --hitcount 3 --rcheck --seconds 60 -j DROP
```

... this only blocks the ICMP traffic, but not the other traffic from the IP address(es).  Why is this?

Comment: @Scott thank you. You are right, it is a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-j DROP` rule affects only traffic
that has been redirected into the `BAN` chain —
and that’s only the ping traffic. 
Other traffic from the blacklisted IP address(es)
never gets into the `BAN` chain,
and so it never hits the `-j DROP` rule.